# Multiplicativity of $\operatorname{Tot}_n$

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Suppose $R^\bullet$ is a cosimplicial ring. I think this induces a ring structure on $\operatorname{Tot}(R^\bullet)$-- I couldn't find a classical reference, but I did find a recent paper of Batanin and Davydov (https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.13039) which seems to do this in much more generality. However, this does not (to my knowledge) answer the following question:

Does the multiplication on $R^\bullet$ induce a multiplication on $\operatorname{Tot}_0(R) \leftarrow \operatorname{Tot}_1(R) \leftarrow \cdots$ as a filtered object? I.e. I'm expecting multiplication maps $\operatorname{Tot}_i(R) \wedge \operatorname{Tot}_j(R) \to \mathrm{Tot}_{i+j}(R)$. (In fact all I need for my intended application is a well-behaved multiplication $\operatorname{Tot}_i(R)\wedge \operatorname{Tot}_i(R) \to \operatorname{Tot}_i(R)$ which should be implied by this.) If the multiplication on $R^\bullet$ is associative / commutative, can you say the same about this induced multiplication on the system $\{\operatorname{Tot}_i(R)\}_i$?

Comment: Multiplication's given by the Alexander-Whitney cup product. It's associative but not commutative. Since it respects the grading, it respects that filtration.